# Change constant variables defined in a library depending on the application that uses the library [Android-Java]

Tags: java, android, variables, constants, android-library

I have a android library project that contains many of the common code for 2 Android projects.

In my library project I have a `ContentProvider` implementation and a `Service` implementation.

The plan is to extend these 2 classes in each project and specify them in Manifest file separately.

But I have a class with constants as follows,

```
public class LiquidContentProviderContract {

    public static String CONTENT_AUTHORITY;

    public static String ANDROID_APPLICATION_TABLE = "androidapp";

    public static Uri BASE_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY);

    public static Uri CONTENT_URI_ANDROID_APPLICATION =
            BASE_CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(ANDROID_APPLICATION_TABLE).build();

}
```

But I want to change this CONTENT_AUTHORITY variable according to my application that I am going to use this library.

What is the best way of doing this? What are the common design patterns that support this sort of implementation.

I tried the following to see if I can at least get this thing to work,

```
public class Foo{

     public static void main(String []args){

        Newfile.te = "Nothing";

        System.out.println(Newfile.te);

        System.out.println(Newfile.tf);

     }
}
```

and

```
public class Newfile{

  public static String te = "Mango";

  public static String tf= Newfile.te + " Eating";

}
```

out put was,

```
Nothing
Mango Eating
```

But I was expecting,

```
Nothing
Nothing Eating
```

Thanks

Comment: consider using android studio and implementing build flavors. http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think design wise this approach is a good idea. But since it is Android there are lot of Framework related classes that limits injecting things into the class. In such cases, I use this technique.

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        Newfile.te = "Nothing";
        System.out.println(Newfile.te);
        System.out.println(Newfile.getTf());
    }
}

public class Newfile {
    public static String te = "Mango";

    // instead of using this public static String tf= Newfile.te + " Eating";

    public static String getTf() {
        return Newfile.te + " Eating";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you got that is output is that static initializers are calculated once, at the time the class is loaded.  When the class is loaded te is mango, so it assigns tf to Mango Eating and will never be recalculated.  When is the class loaded?  Right before the first instance of its use.  What you want to do will never work.

Truthfully, it sounds like from what you want that you ought to rethink your architecture-  what you want sounds like it should be a parameter to the library rather than a static value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer for my first part. +1 will eventually come with my reputation :).